# Calculate the frequency of all the keywords (single word and multi word) appearing in a document

Tags: python-3.x, findall

I want to calculate the frequency of some keywords (single word or multi word) appearing in a document. I am using regex for this purpose. Below is my implementation:

```
def calculate_keyword_frequency(keyword_list, text):
    frequency = {}
    for keyword in keyword_list:
        frequency[keyword] = len(re.findall(keyword, text))
    return frequency

keyword_list = ["your work", "bodily injury"]
text = "your work needs to be finished. before you leave, your work should be done!"

result = calculate_keyword_frequency(keyword_list, text)

# Print the frequency for each keyword
for keyword, frequency in result.items():
    print(f"{keyword} = {frequency}")
```

This will use the re.findall() function to find all the keywords and their frequency appearing in text.

I have 2 issues with the above approach:

1.) The logic will return the frequency of all the keywords present in the list. But if the keywords are present in the text but in a different way, `your  work` or `your, work`  instead of `your work`(extra character) or any other case where the keyword is present but not in the form of the matching keyword present in the list, the logic will not detect that keyword. **Basically the above logic is not robust enough.**

2.) Is there any other way or library I can use to calculate the frequency of the keywords in the list? The workaround should be more robust than the above logic.

Thank you!

**EDIT1:** : I know I can write a regex pattern which can solve the first issue. But this brings up another issue in that, the `keyword_list` can have hundreds of keywords. Writing a regex pattern for all of them is not feasible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace spaces in each keyword with a regex pattern of `\W+` so that it will match one or more non-word characters instead of just a space:

```
import re

def calculate_keyword_frequency(keyword_list, text):
    frequency = {}
    for keyword in keyword_list:
        frequency[keyword] = len(re.findall(keyword, text))
    return frequency

keyword_list = ["your work", "bodily injury"]
patterns = {r'\W+'.join(k.split()): k for k in keyword_list}
text = "your  work needs to be finished. before you leave, your, work should be done!"

result = calculate_keyword_frequency(patterns, text)

# Print the frequency for each keyword
for keyword, frequency in result.items():
    print(f"{patterns[keyword]} = {frequency}")
```

This outputs:

```
your work = 2
bodily injury = 0
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/RepentantCheerfulShoutcast

Comment: Yes I am aware of this option. But is there any other non regex way of doing this? Or is regex my only option?

Comment: If you were already aware of this option then you should've included it in your question instead of letting answers spend time writing what you already knew. Regex is designed to do this after all. You can always write a specialized parser to scan the string character by character instead, but why reinvent the wheel when the right regex can already do it well? What concerns do you have with regex?

Comment: The issue I have with regex is that there are going to be a lot of keywords present in the `keyword_list`. Writing a regex pattern for all of them is not feasible.

Comment: This is why I'm not modifying your `keyword_list`, but instead I'm making `patterns` a programmatically generated dict of regex-to-keyword mapping from the plain keywords in `keyword_list`.

Comment: Ok got it! Also can I use `*` instead of `+` in the `pattern`? I think that would make it more robust. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes you can use `*` instead of `+` if you want keywords with nothing between each word to match as well (for example, if you want "yourwork" to match).